# gedit - cannot open display

Tags: 14.04, gedit, hadoop

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and for installing Hadoop I created hadoop user as **hduser**. When I try to open `~/.bashrc` using **gedit** am getting an error as follows,

```
hduser@arul-java ~ $ gedit ~/.bashrc

(gedit:9254): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 
hduser@arul-java ~ $
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: An X-Server is running?

Comment: Use `nano ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @A.B. how to solve it ?

Comment: Solve what? Start a X-Server?

Comment: @A.B. nano working thanks, but can you tell me how to open with gedit ?

Comment: Not without an graphical environment.

Comment: @A.B. I have no idea about X-Server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29926/discussion-between-a-b-and-arul).

Comment: @A.B. actually my gedit is working good on other cases, in this case only I am getting an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally a server with Hadoop doesn't have a graphical environment and after a brief conversation in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29926/discussion-between-a-b-and-arul) turned out that it is not at all absolutely necessary to use `gedit`. It concerns only the processing of a configuration file and that's done quicker with `nano` or `vi`.